# react test state doesnt render while testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

i try to write test to my project.

```
<tbody>
     
      {
        filteredJobs?.map(job => (
          <tr key={job.id}>
            <td className='jobName'>{job.jobName}</td>
            <td className='row'>
              <button data-testid={`editButton-${job.id}`} className='edit' onClick={() => handleEditModalOpen(job.id)}><EditIcon /></button>
              <button className='delete' onClick={() => handleDeleteModalOpen(job.id)} ><DeleteIcon /></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))
      }
    </tbody>
```

i have state and i displays it in table. and i want to acces to edit buton with `data-testid='editButton'`.

in test.js, i try to access with `const editButton=screen.getByTestId('editButton');` and i get error like `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="editButton"]`. i think filteredJobs state doesnt render at same time.because when i make debug, i cant see that data in log. i need to wait filteredJobs.map function render and then i will call edit button. but i cant find how i can. how can i do ?

test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render,screen, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import JobsProvider from '../../context/JobsContext';
import JobListTable from './JobListTable';

test('edit modal click check',async ()=>{
  render(
    <JobsProvider>
      <JobListTable />
    </JobsProvider>
  ); 
  const editButton=screen.getByTestId('editButton-1');


});
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: sorry i forget added. i get error like TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="editButton"]

Comment: Can you add your full test code?

Comment: i added test code @LuisPauloPinto

Comment: You would need to add more context, like where/when is `filteredJobs` defined?

Comment: oh. yes filtered jobs created another component. i give it that component as prop. so i added filteredjobs's component in render. it's work. thank you @Camilo

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what kind of error you get, but I see following problem: *filteredJobs* is an array and you iterate over it with map(). So in most cases you wont get ONE but MANY edit buttons, but what you do currently is, you give every edit button the same test id "editButton". To avoid this, either use some id value in your filteredJobs elements or at least add index when iterating. I see you indeed have job.id, so try this:

```
data-testid={`editButton-${job.id}`}
```

Comment: doesnt work. i get again same error. "TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="editButton-1"]"